# Try catch with multiple async functions without interupting the flow

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a `Flow Controller` like method in NestJS/TypeScript.

Let me copy paste the method here (with some changes):

```js
async my_flow_implementation(....) {

    checkIfCanbeDeleted = some_method(...);

    if (checkIfCanbeDeleted) {
 
         step1_status = await step1_execution(..);
         step2_status = await step2_execution(..);
                  ........
         stepn_status = await stepN_execution(..);
    }
}
```

Now any of this stepN_execution(...) can potentially fail. And based on the type of failure we may want to do some code handling and proceed with the next step. But the failure of a particular step should not interrupt the whole flow.

Something like (just a snippet):

```js
         step1_status = await step1_execution(..);
         if (step1_status == FAILURE) {
            // Do some handling ..
            // _but_ continue with next step
         }
```

So one solution, naively, I am thinking as :

```js
try {
    step1_status = await step1_execution(..);
} catch (error1) {
    // handle error
    try {
    step2_status = await step2_execution(..);
    } catch (error2) {
        try {
            step3_status = await step3_execution(..);
        } catch (error3) {
               ...........
        }
    }
}
```

But it looks pretty right-drifted code, not elegant.

What is my alternative here?

Any pseudu code/idea will help (as it's a project, can't fully share the code).

Comment: you could use the `.catch()` callback and do your error handling in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.catch()` callback of the promise.

Here is an example:

```js
   let step1_status = await someFunction().catch((error) => {
    /* Do error handling */
  });

  let step2_status = await someFunction().catch((error) => {
    /* Do error handling */
  });

  let step3_status = await someFunction().catch((error) => {
    /* Do error handling */
  });
```

Comment: Ok. Thank You Very Much.
One question through.
What should be the type of the 'step1_status'? Like it can any of the two types - the return type of the someFunction(..) or the error type (say HttpException).
Now what is the best way I should describe both the types of the `step1_status` such that it will remain property typed as well (as I am in TypeScript).
Thanks.

Comment: I don't really get your question, could you clarify? Because I have no clue what `step1_execution` does, I can't know what the return type of the function is.

Comment: Suppose the return type of step1_execution is boolean. Now what should be the type of step1_status ? Because now it can be boolean or an error type (error type let's say is HttpException).

Comment: It should be a boolean because `step1_execution` shouldn't return a HttpException, it should `throw` a HttpException.